# Xamarin forms - Open file as stream

Tags: android, azure, stream, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

This might be a very simple question but I'm always confused when we're talking about streams.
I'm trying to open a file in my Xamarin Forms project in the Android part of it.
I have a Java.IO.File which I would like to convert into a stream to be able to send it to an Azure Blob Storage with that simple function :

```
        public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(Stream stream)
        {
        await this.container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var name = "Photo_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var fileBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        await fileBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

        return name;
        }
```

However, I can't seem to be able to use StreamReader from the Android part with 
StreamReader or OutputStreamWriter.
Did anyone encounter the same issue ?
Thank you !

Comment: You should be able to just use the StreamReader. Why do you think that doesn't work?

Comment: I am indeed to use StreamReader... My bad.
Don't know what I did wrong the last time.

Comment: Updated it to an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to just use the `StreamReader` class from System.IO. Sample code could look something like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("photo.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
```

Don't forget to dispose them after you are done.

For more detail on how to upload to Azure containers, check out the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/storage/azure-storage/).

Comment: Isn't System.IO windows specific?

Comment: Nope, why would it be? :)

Comment: Okay I found out it isn't, but there's still a problem. Xamarin only has one filepicker. You only need a filepath but that filepicker loads the entire file into memory when picked. I don't know how to get only a file path in Xamarin.