# Unable to create stream from stored image for byte[] conversion

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

I've been struggling with this implementation for a few hours now and can't seem to find any solutions wherever I look (SO, Xamarin Forums, Google etc)...

In this current scenario I have a few images in `.Droid.Resources.Drawable` which I wish to access and convert into a `byte[]` from my shared code. This is due to the fact that I wish to test the full span of my **CRUD** functionality on a REST API I've set up as an end-point for our server.

The images show up fine in the application, but for some reason I simply can't seem to warp my head around the process of converting these images to a `byte[]` in Xamarin. I've done it countless times in 'normal' **C#**...

Sorry if the code is a bit messy, but I'm sure you get the idea.

1. I want to get an image from `.Droid` storage (will be ported for iOS later)
2. Convert said image into a `byte[]`
3. Send that `byte[]` representation to my API.

In the code's current state I'm getting this error:

> C#: An instance of an abstract class can not be created

Where I'm attempting to create a new Stream (`new Stream(sauce)`)

---

The below example is based on snippets found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532462/is-there-a-cross-platform-solution-to-imagesource-to-byte/27532867#27532867) and full credit goes to Sten and Vincent.

```
   /*
    * Takes an arbitrary string as a token, updates a record with dummy data and a placeholder_image.
    */
    public async Task<string> PostUpdateFoundation(string arbitrary, Image img)
    {

        ImageSource sauce = ImageSource.FromFile("abc.png");
        byte[] byte_img = FromStreamToByte(new Stream(sauce)); //error occurs here
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in!");
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var content = new StringContent(arbitrary);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(String.Format("http://some.api.to.test.com?s={0}&img={1}", arbitrary, byte_img), content); 
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
        return result;

    }
   /*
    * Attempts to convert an stream (based on image source) into a byte[].
    */
    public static byte[] FromStreamToByte (Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what or where is the error according to you?

Comment: Right, sorry for missing that. Just getting so damn confused by all this.
In the code's current state I'm getting a "C#: An instance of an abstract class can not be created" error on the line where I'm attempting to create a `new Stream(sauce)`.

Comment: Why are you trying to include a byte array as a query string parameter? What would you expect that to do? You're effectively calling `ToString()` on a `byte[]`, which is *really* not going to be what you want. I suspect you want your image data to be in the body of the request, either as binary data or (if you need text as well) as base64.

Comment: Why bother creating an `ImageSource` at all? Why not just create a `FileStream` to read the file?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it would seem as if Xamarin doesn't have a `FileStream` implementation. Either that or my current version doesn't have one.

Comment: Actually it does in the platform specific projects. So you will need the DependencyService, had about the same question some time ago; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341155/xamarin-forms-open-file-as-stream/43342504#43342504

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Plugin.Media](https://components.xamarin.com/view/mediaplugin)

```
            byte BImageSource = ReadFully(file.GetStream());
            var bytes = new byte[file.GetStream().Length]; //file is from the plugin and contains your image
            file.GetStream().Position = 0;
            file.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.GetStream().Length);
            BImageSource = ReadFully(file.GetStream()); //BImageSource is your resource in bytes

    byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!